# How to follow oneway directions using sld?

Tags: geoserver, labeling, sld, direction

I want to show oneway directions of streets using SLD in geoserver. I follow [this instruction](https://geoserver.org/tips%20and%20tricks/user%20perspectives/2009/04/02/follow-the-arrows.html) but i still have a problem with directions of arrows. Most of all arrows get south to north and west to east direction. The arrows don't follow the direction of the lines. How to solve this issue?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
  xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>oneway_ir</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Title>A gold line style</Title>
      
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
       
       <Rule>
               <MaxScaleDenominator>2000000</MaxScaleDenominator>
      <TextSymbolizer>
        <Label>
          <ogc:Literal>&#x2192;</ogc:Literal>
        </Label>
        <Font>
          <CssParameter name="font-family">Lucida Sans</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="font-size">18</CssParameter>
        </Font>
        <Fill>
          <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
        </Fill>
         <VendorOption name="followLine">true</VendorOption>
        
      </TextSymbolizer>
            
    </Rule>
    
          </FeatureTypeStyle>
        </UserStyle>
      </NamedLayer>
    </StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

[image]

Comment: OK, I don't see the issue - those arrows are following the lines as expected.

Comment: @IanTurton i tested the direction with the correct direction. arrows are not following the lines

Comment: are you sure the lines are digitised in the "correct" direction?

Comment: @IanTurton yes. I'm sure. I tested the direction of the lines in ArcGIS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Labels that might be looking "downwards" are automatically flipped to keep them readable. You can turn that off using the "forceLeftToRight" vendor option:

https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/reference/labeling.html#forcelefttoright